# Change a button's characteristic outside class programatically

Tags: swift, class

In the code below, I want to be able to change the visibility of a button in another class, but when I try to change button.isHidden to false, the button still doesn't show up.

View Controller 1:

```
override viewDidLoad(){
     button.isHidden = true
}
```

View Controller 2:

```
ViewController1().button.isHidden = false
```

How can I change the button's visibility from another controller

Comment: You need to have a reference to the button somehow, or a reference to ViewController1. It depends how you've got your code set up. What relationship does ViewController1 have to ViewController2?

Creating a new `ViewController1` with `ViewController1()` means you have two `ViewController1`s, so changing the button on one has no effect on the original `ViewController1`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ViewController1()` creates a `ViewController1` instance instead of working with the `ViewController1` instance that has already been instantiated.

To access properties (in this case the button) of `ViewController1` from `ViewController2`, you have to pass a reference to that button from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` and change the properties through that reference.

You need to set the reference in your `prepare(for segue)` function in `ViewController1`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        nextVC.button = sender as! UIButton
    }
}
```

You also need to set the segue to manual and call it in `ViewController1` by `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self.button)`

You need to create the property in `ViewController2` and access it like this:

```
class ViewController2 {
   var button:UIButton?

   func showButtonOnVC1(){
       guard let button = self.button else { return }
       button.isHidden = false
   }

}
```